# Modificar o tamanho de um array em tempo de execução

Tags: java, array

Estou fazendo uma aplicação java, e usei netbeans para construir a tela. Nessa tela tenho um botão que gera números aleatórios e os coloca dentro de um array, porém não consigo mudar o tamanho dele quando está em execução.

O que fiz: Criei uma variável "tam" e atribui ao vetor

```
int vetor[] = new int[tam];
```

Então criei um botão que atualiza a variável "tam", definida em um campo.

```
tam = Integer.parseInt(txtTamanho.getText());
```

Porém quando gero o vetor novamente ele continua com o mesmo tamanho.

Comment: Impossivel, o tamanho de um array é imutável. O que você pode fazer é criar um novo com o tamanho maior e repopular, ou utilizar Collections.

Comment: Não estará a procura de `ArrayList<Integer>` ?

Comment: Eu colocaria no botão: `vetor = new double[tam]`

Comment: Você coloca esses números no vetor com qual finalidade? Para que você vai usar esse vetor?

Comment: Esse vetor guarda o valor dos produtos que tenho, o tamanho do vetor indica o numero de produtos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O tamanho de um array não pode ser alterado após ele ser criado. Duas possibilidades é criar um novo array com o novo tamanho repopular ele com os dados do antigo(desde que o novo seja maior que o antigo):

```
int[] newArray =  new int[oldArray.length];

for(int i = 0; i < oldArray.length; i++) {
    newArray[i] = oldArray[i];

}
```

ou utilizar [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), que é uma lista flexivel e com tamanho dinâmico.

```
ArrayList<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<>();
lista.add(1);
lista.add(2);
...
lista.add(n);
```

Comment: Obrigado, vou tentar usar arraylist